# load php array to javascript (and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php file (`test.php`) that has the following content:

```
<?php
$ar = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry');
?>
```

When I now want to use the `$ar`variable in a javascript code inside my `test.html`file (which looks as follows):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF8">
    <script src="test.php" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  </head>

  <body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var ar = <?php echo json_encode($ar) ?>;
     alert(ar)
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I keep getting the error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` (in Chrome and Safari). I read through many other examples, where this error was mentioned, however, none of the proposed solutions worked for me. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: If you're seeing that PHP code *in your browser* then that means the PHP isn't executing at all.  (Probably because it's an `.html` file.)  Additionally, unless you include `test.php` *in your PHP code*, your second page isn't going to have `$ar` defined anyway.

Comment: you can't put php code in a html file

Comment: yep, was a permission thing. thanks for helping me!

Comment: You can't use `<?php ?>` inside `.html` file.